# mysqld is suddenly taking too much memory and my laptop is getting hotter

Tags: 14.04, mysql, temperature, memory-usage

I have been using ubuntu 14.04 for a while but really new to linux command line stuffs. I mainly use it for Java/android/web development purposes.

Sometimes I notice my laptop gets more hot than usual, sometimes even around high temperatures while using Eclipse+tomcat. But most of the time the temp is really normal. So, every time I see my laptop getting too hot, I check the running services and every time I find "mysqld" taking unusually more memory than normal. Like normally its taking around 40-60mb of memory, but when I see my laptop is getting really hot, I check the memory usage and I find `mysqld` taking around 500mb of memory!

For a month I didnt see that happening again. But yesterday my ubuntu made an update and since then I am having this issue again. Can anyone help me solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check your buffer_sizes, i assume you are using innodb,

set the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to a value which is lower than that of current one.

The number of connections can also makes use of large memory, so set your `max_connections` value as low as possible

make sure you have closed all the open connections in your application once they done their job.

If there are any long running queries, it affects the performance too. You need to check your slow query log to find those queries.

Check by `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` which shows the queries that are running and waiting for some other resources. You can refine those queries to make them complete quick.

Comment: Thanks, yes the default is innodb. I am checking on these. But here's one more thing: when I start my ubuntu and don't run any programs, its taking a lot of memory. But when I open eclipse run my web application and keep working, I noticed it is going back to normal. But the cpu temperature never gets better.